# How to prevent installing on iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, ios, installation, app-store

Can I prevent users from installing my app on iPhone 3G and 3GS?

I want to support only iPhone 4 and higher, so I don't want the app to be shown in the App Store for 3G and 3GS iPhone users.

Can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Not really a StackOverflow question, but I'm curious; why don't you want your app to be available to additional users?

Comment: Just use Xcode 4.5 to keep your app off of the 3G. The 3G has an armv6 processor which isn't supported by Xcode 4.5. There is no good way to prevent use on the 3GS though.

Comment: @FilipRadelic a good reason, is that someone does not want to a buy a iphone3GS and test the app on the device.

Comment: @AlexWien that's a lame reason, you can always find someone with an older device to test your app :) I'm just wondering if OP thinks there is an actual real reason that this app would not run properly on older devices.

Comment: @FilipRadelic It not a perfect reason, but you cannot always find one that have a specific device with a specific version. Further you have to test it, you cannot r ely on a user that he intensivly test all features of your app. You have to buy one used.

Comment: @FilipRadelic - Since my app needs a very high camera resolution - I want to block iPhone devices under iPhone 4. For 3GS users - the app won't work good enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify in your app's device capabilities that it requires a front-facing camera and/or a gyroscope. iPhone 3GS has neither of those things.

See this article: http://www.appsbynight.com/2012/02/20/lock-users-from-running-an-app-on-older-ios-devices/

Keep in mind that there may be some risk of Apple taking issue with you requiring the front-facing camera if you don't actually use it in your app. Or maybe they won't care. I guess it's a bit of a lottery.

Comment: Actually, there shouldn't be any conflict. UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities has been used in this manner for years, and I believe it's how apple determines the device your app can run on (you can find that at the bottom of all App descriptions).  It's really quite smart +1

Comment: Maybe it's not really an issue with Apple. All the better!